# convert C# code to php for encrypt and decrypt

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I try to convert this code to php, but i can't and always i get different result in C# and PHP
Here is my C# code for encrypt and decrypt :

```
private static readonly byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234567812345678");
private const int keysize = 256;
private string pass = "sample";

public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}

public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

and this is my php code :

```
$iv = "1234567812345678";
$out = null;
$key = "sample";
foreach ($iv as $i) { $out .= chr(ord(substr($i,0,1))); }
$res = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, implode($out));
```

Comment: Note that mcrypt is abandon-ware, it has not been updated in years, it is best not to use it.

Comment: Don't use a fixed IV. It should be randomly chosen for every encryption, so that semantic security can be achieved. It doesn't have to be secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. A common way is to prepend it to the ciphertext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The keys are not the same. C# is extending the key with `PasswordDeriveBytes` which is a good method. PHP mcrypt is extending they key with nulls. You need the extended (256-bit) keys to be the same.
2. The padding is not the same. Unencrypted data needs to be a multiple of the block size (128-bits for AES) and if it isn't always that padding must to be added. C# is not specifying any padding and will expect the data to be a multiple of the block size (128-bits). PHP will by default add null padding which is non-standard and will not work for binary data. You need to add common padding, the standard is PKCS#7 (aka PKCS#5), See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). C# supports PKCS#5 but for mcrypt you will have to do it in your code (the mcrypt developers were Bozos and did not provide standard padding).
3. Rijndael supports multiple bock sizes, it is not clear what the C# default block size is. If what you want is AES (it should be) the block size needs to be 128-bits.
4. Given that the MSDN documentation does not specify defaults it is best to explicitly set the block size, key size, mode and padding.

Comment: Thanks for your info and help, however after my try till now i can't get correct result can you please give me sample code ? is it possible for you ?

Comment: I don't have C# available but there should be many examples on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code will not run on PHP 5.6 as the key size is wrong, it must be 32 bytes.

Said that, on previous versions PHP was padding the key with \0's to reach the correct key length, but in C# you're creating derived bytes (what indeed is correct) to get enough bytes for your key, which ends in different keys used on C# and PHP.

As a proof, create a key with 32 bytes (32 chars) and use directly those 32 bytes as key, both in PHP and C#, in that way it should work.

But at the end you will need a common way to derive the bytes both on PHP and C# to finally have a consistent keying code, an example can be to use a SHA-256 hash to generate the key.